# Local time specific unit test fails

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit.net, datetimeoffset

I am developing a dot net core 2.2 console application to convert .csv files to .xml files.

I have a unit test to test the creation of a specific xml filename. Part of the filename is a time. This timepart should always be a local time.
Using dotnet core 2.2 with xUnit.

The test succeeds locally (Netherlands, culture nl-NL), but fails when testing in Azure using a Hosting Agent. This Hosting Agent is hosted somewhere in the US (culture en-US).

To fix this test, I created a specific run scope in a specific culture.
I assumed that the .LocalTime of the DateTimeOffset gives me the culture specific local time, but it stays in nl-NL when I debug it in VS2019.

Why ?

Here are some code parts (removed some code for better reading):

```
public class OutputIdentifierServiceTests
{
   [Fact(DisplayName = "Valid filename is created")]
   public void GetOutputIdentifier_ReturnsFilename()
   {
       // Arrange

       // utc time          = 16:52:33
       // local nl-NL time  = 18:52:33

       using (new CurrentCultureScope("en-US"))
       {
           var currentTimeUtc = new DateTimeOffset(2019, 6, 14, 16, 52, 33, TimeSpan.Zero);

           _systemClockServiceMock.SetupGet(s => s.UtcNow).Returns(currentTimeUtc);

           var sut = CreateSut();

           // Act
           var filename = sut.GetOutputIdentifier();

           // Assert
           Assert.Equal("20190614T165233", filename);
       }
   }
}
```

And the CurrentCultureScope class:

```
public class CurrentCultureScope : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly CultureInfo _culture;
        private readonly CultureInfo _uiCulture;

        private bool _disposed = false;

        public CurrentCultureScope(string name)
        {
            _culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
            _uiCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture;

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(name);
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(name);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _culture;
                    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = _uiCulture;
                }

                _disposed = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the class creating the output identifier:

```
public string GetOutputIdentifier()
        {
            var currentTimeUtc = _systemClockService.UtcNow;

            var localTime = currentTimeUtc.LocalDateTime;

            var creationDate = localTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
            var creationTime = localTime.ToString("HHmmss");

            // code removed
        }
```

Comment: "I assumed that the .ToLocalTime of the DateTimeOffset gives me the culture specific local time, but it stays in nl-NL" you are expecting to get the "local" time while you are forcing the locale to be `nl-NL`?

Comment: The local has nothing to do with the timezone

Comment: Sorry Camilo, I edited the post. The scope must be 'en-US' to simulate the Azure hosting agent. When debugging this with the 'en-US' culture scope, the local time stays in nl-NL...

Comment: @PatrickPeters that's because the culture doesn't affect the timezone at all. BTW `UtcNow` is a static method. There must be a compiler or Intellisense warning that you're calling a static method through an object reference

Comment: Asa for the `CurrentCultureScope` class, that's a very risky idea. It's far safer to pass the CultureInfo as a parameter to any function that accepts it instead of depending on global state. The compiler or Intellisense (can't remember which) emit warnings each time you use call a localizable method without specifying the culture.

Comment: As for why `CultureInfo` doesn't affect either `DateTimeOffset` or `DateTime`, it's because they *are* completely unrelated. *Especially* in the Netherlands and Belgium, you probably have to support at least *three* different UIs (Dutch, German, French, possibly English as well) for the same timezone offset. The end user's/browser's preferred language shouldn't affect the timezone

Comment: This is not a web app, this is a console application, that run's in the Netherlands on prem server. The issue will not be in production, only the unittest fails because local time will different because of the country of the hosting agent.

Comment: This points to another problem with `CurrentCultureScope`. It sets *both* the UI Culture *and* the parsing culture. `CurrentUICulture` is the culture used to pick resources, string messages, etc. It doesn't affect how input is parsed or formatted. That's the job of `CurrentCulture`.

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos : thanks for the comments, you were right on this. I solved it by forcing the local time as NL time using the TimeZoneInfo class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it in the output identifier function (thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos, see comments). The CurrentCultureScope is not needed.

```
 var currentTimeUtc = _systemClockService.UtcNow;

 var nlZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");

 var localTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(currentTimeUtc, nlZone);
```